# Filtering the first row in R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I would like to keep the first observation using the `filter()` function from `dplyr`. I mean, I would obtain many rows satisfying the same criterion from filtering but I only want to keep the first one, without further recurring to `group()` and `distinct()`. Is it possible?

I need to extract from a dataframe the first date stamp and the first date stamp where it appears "Bad".

```
problem = data.frame(
  Status = c("Good",  "Good",  "Bad", "Bad", "Bad"),
  Date_entry = c(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-01-02"), as.Date("2000-01-03"), as.Date("2000-01-04"),as.Date("2000-01-05")),
  Date_status = c(as.Date("1999-01-01"), as.Date("1999-01-01"), as.Date("1999-01-02"), as.Date("1999-01-02"), as.Date("1999-01-02")),
  Value = c(150,20,14,96,04))
```

I can `filter(Date == min(Date))` but then I don't know how to exactly filter out the first "Bad" outcome.
I tried `filter(Date_entry== min(Date_entry) | (Date_status - Date_entry) == min(Date_status - Date_entry))` but still does not work

```
solution = 
  data.frame(Status = c("Good", "Bad"),
             Date_entry = c(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-01-02")),
             Date_status = c(as.Date("1999-01-01"), as.Date("1999-01-02")),
             Value = c(150,20))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Maybe you just need `slice(1)`?

Comment: Can it be used inside filter()?

Comment: It would be  used after `filter()`. But it's a bit unclear exactly what you mean from your description. Again, a reproducible example would make things much clearer.

Comment: You can use `filter(row_number() == 1)`, but if you can relax your "using the `filter` function" requirement, this is what `slice` is made for. Or `head(1)` would also work.

Comment: Oh, I see - reading your question again it seems like you have *some condition* and you only want the first row that meets *that condition*. A reproducible example would make this much clearer...

Comment: Provided reproducible example

Comment: Just want to pick the first "Bad" outcome out of everything else ignoring the remaining ones with filter, because the code is too messed up to recur to grouping

Comment: So you want the first row of the data.frame no matter what it is as well as the first "Bad" row? Your `solution` seems odd because your Bad row has values from the second Good row. What happens if the first row is Bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are asking for could be solved with

```
problem %>% 
  filter(Date_entry==min(Date_entry) | cumsum(Status=="Bad")==1)
```

Here we choose the min date, or we choose the first value of Bad using a `cumsum` (cumulative sum) trick. This number will go up by one each time a "Bad" is observed so we just select the row where it equals 1 (if present).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                 B=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5))
head(df %>% filter(A==1),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
problem %>%
   slice(union(which.min(Date_entry), match('Bad', Status)))
```

-output

```
#  Status Date_entry Date_status Value
#1   Good 2000-01-01  1999-01-01   150
#2    Bad 2000-01-03  1999-01-02    14
```